# How to pass xml content as an string to jaxb parser

Tags: xml-parsing

I have an xml content as string  how can i pass that to jaxb parser to populate the pojo class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><breakfast_menu<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name><food>
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass XML content, you need to wrap the content in a Reader, and unmarshal that instead:

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader("xml string here");
Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

Comment: When i am passing xml content as "?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<note>  
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from>  
  <heading>Reminder</heading>  
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>  
</note>"